# Inheritance between EF4 entities from different assemblies

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Say I'm creating a corp app. One of the entities is Employees, and the HR department has the basic employee data stored here. Then the sales team want in and their operation is placed in a different assembly. Now, even a SalesPerson is an employee, so it would make sense to inherit from the Employee entity, but I don't know how to do that...?

It may be a bad idea to use several entity contexts for all I know? I'm open for suggestions... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can place your POCO entities into different assemblies and you can build inheritance on top of these entities but you still need single ObjectContext and EDMX mapping file which will cover all these entities. You can't simply split your inheritance model into several mapping files.

IMO the only way is to duplicate some mappings among EDMX files for different modules. So for example in your case HR module would have EDMX with Employee mapping and Sales module would have its own EDMX with same Employee mapping and inherited Sales person mapping.

Comment: I really don't want this solution, but in lack of other workable solutions I'll mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, yes, but not with default EF code generation.

You'd need to use **POCO's.**

We have our POCO's in a seperate assembly too, work's fine.

Have a read up on POCO's with EF4. You could use a T4 template to generate the classes, then copy and paste this code into seperate files in the different assembly (i have no idea why the T4 doesn't support file-per-entity generation).

Add a reference to your POCO assembly from your EF project, and EF will use convention-based mapping to use the POCO's.

I'm not 100% sure if it will work with split assemblies though - you might run into problems if the namespace for the assemblies is different. (which they would be).

Worth a shot. Use 1 assembly first, with POCO mapping, make sure that works, then split the assembly and go from there.

Godspeed. :)

Comment: T4 template can generate file per entity - I didn't change anything and it simply works. If you modify template little bit (set path to edmx) you can also place it in different assembly and it will still be able to generate code for you but you have to trigger code generation manually.